# Why does piping into BASH command groups sometimes work?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have used the following command for a while to keep headers on `ps` output.

```
ps aux | { head -1; grep root; }
```

The output will look something like the following.

```
USER               PID  %CPU %MEM      VSZ    RSS   TT  STAT STARTED      TIME COMMAND
root               142   0.0  0.0  1234567   2520   ??  Ss    3:14AM   0:08.03 /usr/sbin/notifyd
root                55   0.0  0.0  7890123   2460   ??  Ss    3:14AM   0:01.94 /usr/sbin/syslogd
...
```

However, when used with other command line programs the output is not as expected.

Take the following `df` example.

```
df -h
```

Outputs the following.

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/disk1s1    466G  103G  362G  22% /
/dev/disk1s4    466G  1.1G  362G   1% /blah/blah/blah
```

Using `df` in a similar syntax as the above example with `ps`.

```
df -h | { head -1; grep disk1; }
```

Outputs the following.

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
```

The expectation is that the output would look essentially the same as the straight `df -h` command.

Why does this differ from `ps`?

I feel that knowing these differences will help me understand BASH processing more completely.

Thank you!

Comment: It's more a question of the C library and I/O buffering.  In the second case, `head -1` read a buffer of data from standard input and printed the first line; the remainder was ignored.  The `grep` did not get to see the data that `head` read, and there was, apparently, nothing relevant left.  In the first case, it isn't quite clear what gives, but probably the behaviour was similar except that the output of `ps aux` had more lines of data after the first buffer full was read by `head`, so `grep` produced those lines that matched after missing an unknown number of lines read by `head`.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 5):

It's because `head` is buffering its input. It reads into a large buffer from the pipe, then starts extracting lines from that buffer. After it has read and printed the first N lines, it exits. Then `grep` starts reading from the pipe. But anything that `head` already read into its buffer is not available.

The reason it seems to work with `ps` is because it produces lots of output, which doesn't fit into this buffer. `grep` is then able to process the rest of the output. But I think if you check carefully you'll see that the result is incomplete.

The output of `df` is much smaller, it all fits into the buffer that `head` uses, so there's nothing left for `grep` to process.

The buffer size is probably something like 4K characters.

You can do what you want with `awk`:

```
df -h | awk 'NR == 1 || /disk1/'
ps aux | awk 'NR == 1 || /root/'
```

`NR` is the line number, so this prints the line if it's the first line or it matches the regexp.

Comment: Not really worth posting as an answer of its own, but the combination `read hdr; echo "$hdr"` would also work in place of `head -1`, since `read` does no buffering, reading one byte at a time until it sees a newline.

Answer (score -1):

Sed(1) can also be used to filter output in this case:

```
    ps aux | sed -n '1p; /root/p'
```

`-n`: Don't echo line of input to standard output after all commands have been applied to it.

`1p`; "address" of line1, with 'p' to print pattern space

`/root/p;` "address" of /regexp/ matching "root", with 'p' to print pattern space

Alternative:

```
    ps aux | sed '1p; /root/p; d;'
```

Some systems may require `ps -aux` i.t. dash (-) to prefix options. Linux and *BSD systems do not (cannot be sure how macOS behaves, I don't have such a system to check out).